# parsing xml using jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I have a xml file. I want to parse it and get the text 
in the tags.

For example I want to extract  "2.6" from the tag infoModelversion.
"echo=hi hello" from the tag ns:description .

My xml file is as shown below.

```
<ns:workflowInvoked 
        xmlns:ns="http://airavata.apache.org/schemas/wft/2011/08" 
        infoModelVersion="2.6">
        <ns:notificationSource 
            ns:serviceID="Workflow1_cbc2c80b_511c_4a5b_9f88_fa789378296b" 
            ns:experimentID="Workflow1_cbc2c80b-511c-4a5b-9f88-fa789378296b" />
        <ns:timestamp>2013-07-26T23:45:37.654+05:30</ns:timestamp>
        <ns:description>echo=hi hello</ns:description><ns:annotation />
        <ns:initiator ns:serviceID="Workflow1_cbc2c80b_511c_4a5b_9f88_fa789378296b" />
</ns:workflowInvoked>
```

I was trying to parse it using the following code.

```
var new_var = $(xml).find("ns:workflowInvoked infoModelVersion").text();
console.log(new_var);
```

I am not getting proper output. Can anybody point out what mistake I am making?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var new_var = $(xml).attr("infoModelVersion");
console.log(new_var);
```

Comment: How will get description.                                            var new_var = $(xml).attr("ns:description"); doesnt work

Comment: `var description = $(xml).find("ns\\:description").text();`  Do you at least try to understand code you are using???

Comment: In var description = $(xml).find("ns\\:description").text(); you are escaping the colon using // . I thought of it but did not do it as it is already enclosed in ""  .

Comment: ya, escaping semi colon